# How to meet quality standard for audio files to upload to the Unity Store?

Tags: unity, assets, audio

I have some 8-bit classical music that I want to release on the Unity store, for the most part the Unity Store Submission Guidelines make sense, but for this one part that goes.

> 2.7.b Audio files are clear and audible. Audio tracks do not exceed -0.3 dB on peak meters.

Was wondering what exactly getting your music up to that standard means? I have read the submission guidelines carefully and I believe I adhere to them, but for this one part that I'm uncertain about.

[Source](https://assetstore.unity.com/publishing/submission-guidelines)

Answer (score 1):

That is talking about volume. It says that the tracks need to be heard and they shouldn't be compressed so much that you can't understand them. Finally, if you were to look at the music under a peak meter, it must not exceed the listed value. Basically, try not to hurt people's ears with your music.